# Swapping the placement of a character in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for a way to change the placement of a character within a cell with a macro, and have not been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.  I've found ways to switch words (such as first name last name), but I need to switch a single character that is attached to the end of a number.

The report that's being filtered in registers negative numbers as:

*2.00-*

and I'm looking for an easy way to switch it to:

*-2.00*

as I am dealing with a massive number of records.  Is there an easy macro that I can use to do this, or do I need to manually change these?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you just need to change the format of the cell?

Comment: I've tried this, and it does nothing for the cells in question.

Comment: So is this cell formatted as "Text" and the number stored in there isn't being stored as a number by excel? If that's the case then you could flip it over to a number using Text-To-Columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select column then Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Next, Advanced, Trailing minus for negative numbers, Ok, Finish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="-",-MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column and insert this formula. Replace A3 with the first cell in question, and then drag it down:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A3,1) = "-", LEFT(A3, LEN(A3)-1) * -1, A3)
```